# Detect Apache web server sturtup programatically

Tags: apache, webserver

Is there any way to know programmatically when [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) and/or deployed application started/restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the mod_status page for Apache (usually at /server-status - see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html).

Then you can parse the output to see what "Restart Time" says.

Comment: We added following to httpd.conf:

<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host localhost
</Location>

but wen we try to access it via url: http://localhost:8082/server-status it gives 500 internal server error in browser.

We also have following output in error.log file: [Sun Jan 17 19:58:31 2016] [crit] [client ::1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /server-status


We kindly ask you for furthet assistance about this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what OS we're talking about here.

Assuming its Linux/Unix, the start time of a process can be output by the [ps command](http://www.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?ps%201) but note that this will (depending on the MPM) return multiple records of different ages for `httpd` - the base process will be the oldest / the parent of the other processes.

On Linux, this information is also exposed in the proc filesystem - but note that a lot of the files describing the process are changed during its lifetime - but the directory (/proc/$PID) and exe (/proc/$PID/exe) don't.

Comment: In our case OS is windows 7.